# some parts of the text retrieved from txt file via fgets got lost in c

Tags: c, size, buffer

I am reading a file called "dictionary.txt" by fgets and print out, but like 10% of the head text from the "dictionary.txt" is lost when I run the program.

I suspect whether it is the size of the buffer is small, but changing MAX_INT to bigger numbers doesn't help either.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_INT 50000

void main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char* inp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_INT);
    int i;
    int isKorean = 0;
    char* buffer[MAX_INT];
    char* ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_INT);

    if (fp = fopen("C://Users//user//Desktop//dictionary.txt", "r")) {
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {
            ptr = strtok(buffer, "/"); //a line is looking like this : Umberto/영어("English" written in Korean)
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(ptr); i++) {
                if ((ptr[i] & 0x80) == 0x80) isKorean = 1; //check whether it's korean
                if (!isKorean) printf("%c", ptr[i]); //if it's not korean, then print one byte
                else {
                    printf("%c%c", ptr[i], ptr[i + 1]); //if it's korean, then print two bytes
                    i++;
                }
                isKorean = 0;
                printf("\n");
            }
            ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
            printf("tagger:%s\n", ptr); //print the POS tagger of the word(it's in dictionary)
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: If that code compiles and runs successfully that it would be somewhat surprising.  It's rarely the case that one can actually allocate an automatic array of size `MAX_INT` (i.e. `buffer`).  `MAX_INT` is implementation-dependent, but it is *definitely* greater than 30,000, and and most systems these days it is greater than 2,000,000,000.  That is ridiculously more than you need to accommodate lines from a formatted text file.  Even a million characters is large for the plain text of an entire novel, and you're probably reserving more than 7000 times that among your three allocations.

Comment: What's worse, you immediately leak one of those three enormous allocations by overwriting the value of `ptr`, and you appear to let another of the three languish, unused.

Comment: `char* buffer[MAX_INT]; ...  
     while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)) {` makes little sense.    Type is wrong for `fgets()`.  This implies learners number one mistake : lack of warnings.  Enable all warnings and save time.

Comment: Good point, @chux.  So it's an *even more* absurd allocation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It was just a trial to use the HUGE number because I firstly suspected whether my buffer was too small. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you may be confusing `MAX_INT` defined in this code as 50000 with `INT_MAX` defined in limits.h.  Just bad macro naming.

Comment: Also if the file contains Unicode Korean, it is not a given both bytes of a _wide character_ are printable characters ( `printf("%c%c", ptr[i], ptr[i + 1]);` might do nothing visible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function fgets has this syncpsis:

```
char *
 fgets(char * restrict str, int size, FILE * restrict stream);
```

So why make buffer as pointer array?
`char buffer[MAX_INT]` is what we need.
And the following statement:
`if (fp = fopen("/Users/weiyang/code/txt", "r"))` is not safe, it’s better to add parentheses after assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer.

By adding below after the "ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");" just worked. I also had to do something with the tagger part because it is also written in Korean.

```
ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(ptr); i++) {
                printf("%c%c", ptr[i], ptr[i + 1]); //if it's korean, then print two bytes
                i++;
            }
```